# I have trouble configuring authentication in my Asp.net Core API project. I want to use JWT configuration as well as google login screen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, google-authentication, jwt

If I configure without JWT it displays Google Sign-In page but when I configure adding JWT's configuration it does not display Google Sign-In page. Below is the code

Below code is not displaying Google Sign-In page

```
protected override void RegisterAppInitialServicesToCollection(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var jwtConfig = GetJwtBearerConfig(configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<TContext>();
        services.AddScoped<SysEntitiesBasic>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<TContext>());
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        var googleSettings = configuration.GetSection("GoogleSettings");
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(); ;
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = jwtConfig.ValidateIssuer,
                ValidateAudience = jwtConfig.ValidateAudience,
                ValidateLifetime = jwtConfig.ValidateLifetime,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtConfig.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
                ValidIssuer = jwtConfig.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = jwtConfig.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtConfig.SecurityKey))

            };
        })
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = googleSettings.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = googleSettings.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

The below one displays the Google Sign-In page.

```
 protected override void RegisterAppInitialServicesToCollection(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TContext>();
        services.AddScoped<SysEntitiesBasic>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<TContext>());
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        var googleSettings = configuration.GetSection("GoogleSettings");
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(); ;
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = googleSettings.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = googleSettings.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

I need the first option working as I want to make use of JWT for authentication and Google page for Signing-In. When it fails to display the Sign-In page it comes up with below page
[image]